# How to create htaccess rewrite rules for 301-redirects

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I need to 301-redirect some pages from my old domain to new domain with another of catalog structure. How to create .htacess rewrite rules for conditions like this:

http://www.name.domain/product1.html
to

https://another-name.else-domain/language-1/catalog/product-1

**and**

http://www.name.domain/product2.html
to

https://another-name.else-domain/language-2/catalog-2/product-2

**and**

http://www.name.domain/
or 
http://name.domain/
to

https://another-name.else-domain/homepage/

**and**

http://www.name.domain/any-else-pages
to

https://another-name.else-domain/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect in htaccess in most cases by using a couple options. If its all URLs `Redirect 301 / https://example.com/` for single URLs `Redirect /path/to/old/file/old.html https://www.example.com/new/file/new.html`. Hope that helps get you going.